# Type variable always returns null when running the GetTypes() method

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I have been running into a rather frustrating issue. I am attempting to authenticate a user against an Active Directory, and in order to do so I pass my users variables into the following class.

```
        public static ILdapAuthentication CreateInstance(string domainAndUser, string password, string ldapPath)
    {
        string[] dllPaths = Directory.GetFiles(ExecutingAssemblyDirectory, "*.dll");

        List<Assembly> listOfAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();

        foreach (var dllPath in dllPaths.Where(x => x.Contains("ActiveDirectoryAuthentication")))
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
            listOfAssemblies.Add(assembly);
        }

        Type type = null;

        int foundTypes = 0;
        foreach (var assembly in listOfAssemblies)
        {
            type =
               assembly.GetTypes()
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(ILdapAuthentication)));

            if (type == null)
                continue;

            foundTypes++;
        }

        if (foundTypes == 0)
            throw new Exception("ActiveDirectoryAuthentication DLL not found.");

        if (foundTypes > 1)
            throw new Exception("Only one ActiveDirectoryAuthentication DLL must be used.");

        return Activator.CreateInstance(type, domainAndUser, password, ldapPath) as ILdapAuthentication;
    }
```

The issue occurs in the foreach loop, as I attempt to get my Types, it always returns null, and doesn't even hit the Interface (ILDPAuthentication) code below.

```
    public interface ILdapAuthentication
{
    bool IsActiveDirectoryUserValid();
}
```

which invokes the following code:

```
    public class LdapAuthentication : ILdapAuthentication
{
    private string DomainAndUser { get; set; }
    private string Password { get; set; }
    private string LdapPath { get; set; }

    public LdapAuthentication(string domainAndUser, string password, string ldapPath)
    {
        this.DomainAndUser = domainAndUser;
        this.Password = password;
        this.LdapPath = ldapPath;
    }

    public bool IsActiveDirectoryUserValid()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.DomainAndUser.Contains('\\'))
                throw new Exception("Domain User is invalid.");

            string[] userLogin = this.DomainAndUser.Split('\\');
            string domain = userLogin[0];
            string userName = userLogin[1];

            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(this.LdapPath, this.DomainAndUser, this.Password);
            object obj = entry.NativeObject;

            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("CN");

            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            if (null == result)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The initial class looks for the DLLs in my application folder called ActiveDirectoryAuthentication which I have copied in.

Comment: Not an answer.. just a suggestion.  Look at your lambda call to assembly.GetTypes()..  to figure out what is going wrong.. DONT use a lambda so you can see the actual entries coming across.  If you need to drill into the list, use a simple foreach loop and evaluate the entries using the immediate window.  I bet you find your problem.

Comment: Please try to avoid gender assumptions about software engineers, as it can be unwelcoming. We tend to trim greetings and salutations anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before - types in a explicitly loaded assembly do not match types in a referenced project. Because you are using:

`i == typeof(ILdapAuthentication)`

you are reliant on the equality comparison for the Type class, which may not return equality when you are expecting it to. I suggest instead you do:

`i.FullName == typeof(ILdapAuthentication).FullName`

which will use a simple string comparison.